# Why is this tooltip collapsed when the others work correctly?

Tags: html, css

Staring hasn't helped. This `<span>` within a `<button>` is supposed to display on `:hover`, and the others do so. But this one doesn't. It has something to do with the css, because if I place the same class on any of them, `.tooltipBR`, the same thing happens.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/briligg/pen/epqNLd?editors=110

Relevant css:

```
.tooltipBR span:after {
  top: 18px;
  right: 100%;
  margin-top: -8px;
  border-right: 8px solid #000000;
  border-top: 8px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 8px solid transparent;
}
:hover.tooltipBR span {
  left: 75%;
  top: -8px;
  margin-left: 100%;
}

.tooltipT, .tooltipTML, .tooltipTL, .tooltipTMR, .tooltipTR, .tooltipL,
.tooltipML, .tooltipR, .tooltipMR, .tooltipB, .tooltipBML, .tooltipBL, .tooltipBBL, .tooltipBMR, 
.tooltipBR {
  position: absolute;
}
.tooltipT span, .tooltipTML span, .tooltipTL span, .tooltipTMR span, 
.tooltipTR span, .tooltipL span, .tooltipML span, .tooltipR span, 
.tooltipMR span, .tooltipB span, .tooltipBML span, .tooltipBL span, .tooltipBBL span, 
.tooltipBMR span, .tooltipBR span {
  position: absolute;
  width:400px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background: #000000;
  height: auto;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  text-align: right;
  visibility: hidden;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.tooltipT span:after, .tooltipTML span:after, .tooltipTL span:after, .tooltipTMR span:after, 
.tooltipTR span:after, .tooltipL span:after, .tooltipML span:after, .tooltipR span:after, 
.tooltipMR span:after, .tooltipB span:after, .tooltipBML span:after, .tooltipBL span:after, 
.tooltipBBL span:after, .tooltipBMR span:after, .tooltipBR span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0; height: 0; 
  z-index: 10;
}
:hover.tooltipT span, :hover.tooltipTML span, :hover.tooltipTL span, :hover.tooltipTMR span, 
:hover.tooltipTR span, :hover.tooltipL span, :hover.tooltipML span, :hover.tooltipR span, 
:hover.tooltipMR span, :hover.tooltipB span, :hover.tooltipBML span, :hover.tooltipBL span, 
:hover.tooltipBBL span, :hover.tooltipBMR span, :hover.tooltipBR span:after {
  visibility: visible;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 8px;
  z-index: 10;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last selector in your last CSS block is `:hover.tooltipBR span:after`, but all of the other selectors in that group are `:hover.foo span`. `.tooltipBR span:after` is handled by your *first* block. I think you need to remove the `:after` from that last selector, to make it like the others.

Comment: Thanks, man. I knew i was being blind to something, but i just couldn't find it and decided to lean on someone else's eyes. Cheers :)

Comment: If this answer is the solution to your question, please mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Sablefoste i had to wait a few minutes before it would let me. good of you to ensure a reminder.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the `:hover` at the end of the id or class name. Instead of `:hover.tooltipT`, code it this way: `.tooltipT:hover`.

Comment: Ah yes, that is the proper syntax. I'll change it.